# Check if array contains object-only-element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to check if an array contains *only* objects.  So I created this function:

```
function arrayContainsObjOnly(arr){
  return arr.join("").replace(/\[object Object\]/g, "") === "";
}
```

Here is how you would use it:

```
// return true
arrayContainsObjOnly([
  {"name" : "juan", "age" : 28},
  {"name" : "pedro", "age" : 25}
]);

// return false
arrayContainsObjOnly([
  {"name" : "juan", "age" : 28},
  "name=pedro;age=25"
]);
```

Is there any cleaner way to do this?  Is using the literal `"[object Object]"` for checking is safe?
I also prefer a non-jQuery solution.

Comment: If any object in the array overrides `.toString()` to provide a custom implementation, then this won't work.  Also, this would not include Array and Function which are each a type of object (not sure if you want to include them or not).

Comment: Yes, Array and Function are also excluded. Array must contains literal objects only.

Comment: Here's an actual glitch.  If one of the array elements is the literal string `"[object Object]"`, you will get a false positive.  So, your method is NOT entirely safe.  You will probably have to check that both `typeof elem === "object"` and that `elem.toString() === "[object Object]"` for each item to be entirely safe.

Comment: Ah, you're right!it didn't cross my mind. I might consider your comment.

Comment: Do you intend this to return `true` if some of the elements are `null` or `undefined` or is that an accident of your implementation?

Comment: @scott - null or undefined are also not accepted, i never thought that those are considered as object. Thanks for pointing out. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually simpler and cleaner, but no less code:

```
function arrContainsObjOnly(arr) {
  return arr.every(function(el) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(el) === '[object Object]';
  });
}
```

**Update**

On second thought, this variant would be better, as it would return `false` on encountering the first non-object:

```
function arrContainsObjOnly(arr) {
  return !arr.some(function(el) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(el) !== '[object Object]';
  });
}
```

Comment: Please note that for **null**, **undefined** elements, this also returns true.

Comment: In what environment?  Not [by spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object.prototype.tostring).  See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString#Using_toString%28%29_to_detect_object_class) for more info.

Comment: `Object.prototype.toString.call(null)` returns `[Object Null]` and `Object.prototype.toString.call(undefined)` returns `[Object Undefined]`.

Comment: Close, `[object Null]`.  But that's the point.  Why do you say this returns true?

Comment: Oh are you saying that the original implementation returned true for those?

Comment: Sorry, @Scott, I missed the point. Carefully considered you answer and yep, that works pretty well. This is much simplified than I thought. it deserves to be a final answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **typeof**  operator

try this one

```
// CASE 1  :

var arrItem = [
    {"name" : "juan", "age" : 28},
    {"name" : "pedro", "age" : 25},
    "name=pedro,age=25"
]

var boolIsAllContainObject = arrItem.every(function(oneItem,key){ 

    if ((typeof oneItem) === "object") { 
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});

console.log(boolIsAllContainObject)   //return false as one element is not object


// CASE 2:

var arrItem = [
    {"name" : "juan", "age" : 28},
    {"name" : "pedro", "age" : 25},
    {"name" : "name=pedro,age=25"}
]

var boolIsAllContainObject = arrItem.every(function(oneItem,key){ 

    if ((typeof oneItem) === "object") { 
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});

console.log(boolIsAllContainObject)   //return true allelement are object
```